# Swift let is mutable in classes why?

Tags: swift, let

Hello everyone I am trying to figure out why the swift code below allows me to assign a new value to the wee string in my class. I thought let was immutable but it works here. Can someone please explain this. Thanks.

```
import Foundation


class MyClass {
    let wee:String

    init?(inInt:Int) {
        let j:String = "what"
        //j = "I shouldn't be able to do this wiht let" // error rightly so
        //println(j)
        self.wee = "wow"
        if inInt != 2 {
            return nil
        }
        self.wee = "hey"
        self.wee = "blas" // I shouldn't be able to do this
    }


}

if let myClass:MyClass = MyClass(inInt: 2) {
    myClass.wee // prints blas
}
```

Comment: Swift 1.2 is supposed to allow you to defer setting of a let variable so you can make a decision about what to assign to it, but it's supposed to only work once, and after setting it it should be a constant, AFAIK.

Comment: self.wee cannot be changed once a value is set even inside an initializer.

Comment: At least in swift 4 it is not supporting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Modifying Constant Properties During Initialization" heading under the [*Initialization*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) section of *The Swift Programming Language* says:

> You can modify the value of a constant property at any point during
>   initialization, as long as it is set to a definite value by the time
>   initialization finishes.

Reading between the lines, and considering your example, it sounds very much like restrictions on setting the value of a constant don't apply to initialization. Further evidence supporting that idea appears earlier in the same section:

> When you assign a default value to a stored property, or set its
>   initial value within an initializer, the value of that property is set
>   directly, without calling any property observers.

It's not unlikely that the constancy of a stored property is enforced by the accessors for that property. If those accessors aren't used during initialization, then it makes sense that you can modify even a constant property as many times as you like during initialization.

The fact that you can't modify `j` in your example after first setting it is due to the fact that `j` is a local constant, not a property. There probably aren't any accessors for `j` at all -- instead the compiler probably enforces access rules for local constants/variables.

Comment: @Caleb, Once a constant property is assigned a value, it can’t be further modified. So, As in the question, self.wee can only assigned once. `self.wee = "hey"` and `self.wee = "blas"` will fail. (even if it is inside an initializer)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are assigning it in initialiser, at a point when object of that class is being created. I just assume, it take any last given value and then creates a constant.
If you would try the same in different function, it would not work. You would get an error.

Comment: I looked up deferring also and found out this is what is happening. The variable get's made into a constant after initialization. I tried to modify it after I made a class and it wouldn't let me unless I made the let a var in the class. It seemed strange. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in swift 4. 
[Apple docs says](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203):

> You can assign a value to a constant property at any point during initialization, as long as it is set to a definite value by the time initialization finishes. Once a constant property is assigned a value, it can't be further modified.

[image]